# Ho do i apply texture to black spots only?

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

I have managed to combine two textures: i turned one to Black/white and multiplied it with another one and it has been applied to whites areas only. But how do i apply a third texture to black spots only?

[image]

Comment: what about using the same technique as you did with the white color, but just invert the color before?

Comment: yeah, it worked out! thanks man)

Comment: Glad I could help